# ¿Alguien sabe xq cuando ejecuto mi código, aparece "Process finished with exit code 0" pero no aparece la parte gráfica?

Tags: pyqt5, qt, pycharm, pyqt6, pyside2

código main:

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

from history import HistoryWindow

from ui_mercado import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.history = HistoryWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.lista = []

    def ingresar(self):
        producto = self.ui.producto.text().strip()
        cantidad = self.ui.cantidad.text().strip()
        precio = self.ui.precio.text().strip()
        total = int(cantidad) * int(precio)
        total = str(total)
        diccionario = {
                        'producto':producto,
                        'cantidad':cantidad,
                        'precio':precio,
                        'total': total
        }
        self.lista.append(diccionario)
        print(self.lista)
        self.ui.producto.setText("")
        self.ui.cantidad.setText("")
        self.ui.precio.setText("")

    def borrar(self):
        self.ui.producto.setText("")
        self.ui.cantidad.setText("")
        self.ui.precio.setText("")

    def historial(self):
        self.history.show_window(self.lista)
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())`
```

Comment: Es posible que tengs un error en la creación de la UI. Ese código está oculto y no podemos verlo

Answer (score 0):

Como dijeron más arriba puedes verificar que no haya errores durante la inicialización de la interfaz de usuario que podrían evitar que se muestre,  o si estás utilizando operaciones asíncronas, asegúrate de que se manejen correctamente

Comment: gracias a los 2, ahí me fijé de hacerlo de vuelta y ahora si anda.